# Save binary string in python

Tags: python, performance, optimization, binary, save

I have a string like that:

```
"10001110...1010"
```

And I want to save that in a file with a binary format and not like a string, to take up the less space.

My solution:
Add a '1' to the beginning of the string and change to integer, like that:

```
a = '0001'
a = '1' + '0001'
b = int(a,2)
```

After, I use the `module pickle` to save that in a file:

```
import pickle
file = open('test.txt','wb')
pickle.dump(b,outf)
file.close()
```

My question is if there is a faster solution?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post.

Comment: Save the file and compress in gz format to save space then use gzip module when reading it

Comment: I'm implementing Huffman compression, If I compress with gzip the compressed file It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A faster solution is to forget adding a '1' to the beginning of the string (did you want '0b'?) and simply use
    a = '0001'
    b = int(a,2)

Comment: If a I pass to int directly without adding '1', '0001' change to 1, and lost the 3 first 0s.